# What's wrong here: Instance member cannot be used on type

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have the following code and I'm confused about this error message:

> Instance member 'mydate' cannot be used on type 'TableViewController'

Code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {    
    let mydate = NSDate()
    let items = [
        (1, 9, 7, "A", mydate),
        (2, 9, 7, "B", mydate),
        (3, 9, 7, "C", mydate),
        (4, 9, 7, "D", mydate)
    ]
```

When I write the following, I can build it but I don't know why the oder snippet is not working:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {    
    let mydate = NSDate()
    let items = [
        (1, 9, 7, "A", nil),
        (2, 9, 7, "B", mydate),
        (3, 9, 7, "C", mydate),
        (4, 9, 7, "D", mydate)
    ]
```

Comment: I ran into the same thing. Your cleanest option is to define them in the class, but populate them in your viewDidLoad() func. This will allow you to nest all you want without these annoying compiling errors.

Comment: @MarkLöwe, that' not "the cleanest solution". And these compiler errors are valid and consistent with the design of the language. The cleanest solution is the solution written here. 
Initialising in `viewDidLoad` may not be even possible in non-viewcontroller-based classes. Let's not mislead people with ridiculous comments.

Comment: internal static var mydate : NSDate;

internal static var items;

This is the easy way to fix this

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `self` before the class is fully initialised. You can either have a getter which will be called every time you access the variable or compute it lazily.

Here is some code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let mydate = NSDate()
    var items : [(Int,Int,Int,String,NSDate)] {
        get {
            return [
                (1, 9, 7, "A", mydate),
                (2, 9, 7, "B", mydate),
                (3, 9, 7, "C", mydate),
                (4, 9, 7, "D", mydate)
            ]

        }
    }
}
```

Lazy computation:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let mydate = NSDate()
    lazy var items : [(Int,Int,Int,String,NSDate)] =  {

            return [
                (1, 9, 7, "A", self.mydate),
                (2, 9, 7, "B", self.mydate),
                (3, 9, 7, "C", self.mydate),
                (4, 9, 7, "D", self.mydate)
            ]


    }()
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: There you go. This works.

Comment: @AboveTheGods quit being such a meanie

Comment: @rockyraccoon, sometimes, the best course of action would be to just nod and smile. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code

```
var items:Array<(Int, Int, Int, String, NSDate)> {
        get {
            return [
                (1, 9, 7, "A", mydate),
                (2, 9, 7, "B", mydate),
                (3, 9, 7, "C", mydate),
                (4, 9, 7, "D", mydate)
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The compiler gets confused because it doesn't know the type of the optional `NSDate`. You can let it know explicitly about the type.

```
let items : Array<(Int, Int, Int, String, NSDate?)> = [
    (1, 9, 7, "A", nil),
    (2, 9, 7, "B", mydate),
    (3, 9, 7, "C", mydate),
    (4, 9, 7, "D", mydate)
]
```

Edit: For the problem with using instance variable, you could initialise your items with a closure.

```
let items : Array<(Int, Int, Int, String, NSDate?)> = {
    let mydate = NSDate()
    return [
        (1, 9, 7, "A", nil),
        (2, 9, 7, "B", mydate),
        (3, 9, 7, "C", mydate),
        (4, 9, 7, "D", mydate)
    ]
    }()
```

Comment: Still getting the error with this fix