# construct an array with UIImageView objects in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift2

In my `ViewController`, I have three `UIImageView` objects which are `IBOutlet` connections as well:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var myImg1: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var myImg2: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var myImg3: UIImageView!

   //ERROR: Instance member 'myImg1' cannot be used by type 'ViewController'
   var myImgArr:[UIImageView] = [myImg1, myImg2, myImg3]
   ...
}
```

I try to put all the three `UIImageView` objects into an array `myImgArr` , but I got complier error : **Instance member 'myImg1' cannot be used by type 'ViewController'** , why? how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're accessing `self` before the class was initialised.

you can define it like this:
 `var myImgArr:[UIImageView]`

and then in the `init` method you can do `myImgArr = [myImg1, myImg2, myImg3]`

Please see the full answer here :
[Whats wrong here: Instance member cannot be used on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693150/whats-wrong-here-instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type)